# how to fix this twitter error using android with twitter4j.core

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I get the following error, how can I fix it?

```
401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
    <error>Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value 'oob'</error>
    <request>/oauth/request_token</request>
</hash>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow all steps [here](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-post-to-twittter-from-java-with-twitter4j-in-10-minutes/). Other [docs](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) about twitter4j.